# Run a NOT headless chrome on a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, docker-machine, e2e-testing

Running chrome on docker machines is only possible when chrome is headless. Unfortunately, headless chrome can't ignore certificate errors which prevents my tests from running.

I'm trying to run an already working NodeJS e2e test environment on a docker container. Most of the tests pass but when a site requires a certificate it can't be accessed. On none headless chrome I can simply ignore the certification error.
The base docker image installed on the container is Node:8

```
{
 browserName: 'chrome',
 chromeOptions: {
   binary: puppeteer.executablePath(),
   args: [
     '--lang=en-US','--headless','--no-sandbox','--ignore-certificate-errors'
   ]
}
```

The expected result is to either run chrome with gui on a docker container or somehow ignore the server certificate errors in headless chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Xvfb. This will allow you to use Chrome with GUI.

The idea is simple: you use virtual desktop. Configuring multiple desktops / displays on a standalone VM took some efforts. With Docker it is simple.

Some examples:

http://www.mattzeunert.com/2018/07/21/running-headful-chrome-on-ubuntu-server.html

https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8

Comment: Thank you very much! The first link you shared was enough, this guy faced the exact same problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way (described [here](https://cntnr.io/running-guis-with-docker-on-mac-os-x-a14df6a76efc) by Nils De Moor) is to let the docker container connect to your local machine's X server.

Say your ip address is `192.168.0.2`.

You can set up a tunnel to you X display on i.e. port 6010, (which corresponds to display `192.168.0.2:10`) with `socat`.  For security, the `range` argument asks `socat` to only accept connections from your machine's IP address.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:6010,reuseaddr,fork,range=192.168.0.2/32 UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\" &
```

Now you can set the `DISPLAY` variable inside the docker container with `-e` when you start it.

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:10 gns3/xeyes
```

In the case of `chrome` there are some more complications, described in the linked post, because chrome requires some more privileges (i.e. add `--privileged` )